# Python Antlr4 Brackets

Tags: python, antlr, grammar

I'm in the middle of writing my grammar, but I can't tackle bracket problem and operations priority. 1 + 3 gives 4, but I need grammar to deal with 
(1 + 3) * 3 = 12 problem and
1 + 3 * 3 = 12.
My grammar has only odd numbers, but it doesn't matter.

Here is my grammar code:

```
grammar PolishNotation;

fragment SINGLE_SPACE   : '\u0020'; // ' '
fragment TABULATION     : '\u0009'; // '\t'
fragment LINE_FEED      : '\u000A'; // '\n'
fragment CARRAIGE_RETURN: '\u000D'; // '\r'
fragment DECEVEN        : '0' | '2' | '4' | '6' | '8';
fragment DECODD         : '1' | '3' | '5' | '7' | '9';
fragment HEXEVEN        : '0' | '2' | '4' | '6' | '8' | 'A' | 'C' | 'E';
fragment HEXODD         : '1' | '3' | '5' | '7' | '9' | 'B' | 'D' | 'F';
fragment OCTEVEN        : '0' | '2' | '4' | '6';
fragment OCTODD         : '1' | '3' | '5' | '7';

Add           : '+';
Subtract      : '-';
Multiply      : '*';
Divide        : '/';
Colon         : ':' -> type(Divide);
Power         : '^';
DoubleMultiply: '**' -> type(Power);
Max           : 'max';
Min           : 'min';

Int           : (DECODD)
              | ([1-9]+ (DECODD | DECEVEN)* (DECODD))
              ;
Hex           : ('0x' (HEXODD))
              | ('0x' [1-F]+ (HEXODD | HEXEVEN)* (HEXODD))
              ;
Oct           : ('0o' (OCTODD))
              | ('0o' [1-7]+ (OCTODD | OCTEVEN)* (OCTODD))
              ;

WhiteSpace    : ( SINGLE_SPACE | TABULATION )+ -> skip;
NewLine       : ( CARRAIGE_RETURN | LINE_FEED )+ -> skip;

number        : Int | Hex | Oct
              ;
operation     : ( number )
                op=( Add
                | Subtract
                | Multiply
                | Divide
                | Power
                | Max
                | Min )
                ( number | operation )
                | '(' operation ')'
              ;
expression    : operation
              | number
              ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar is missing two things here; precedence rules and recursive sub expressions (i.e. brackets).  A typical expression grammar will achieve this by breaking the expression down into a series of *terms* & *factors* as follows:

```
expression    : term ( ( Add | Subtract )  term )* ;
term          : factor ( ( Multiply | Divide ) factor )* ;
factor        : number | '(' expression ')' ;
```

There are numerous tutorials and books available on the theory and practice behind this so I won't duplicate that detail here (try [this one](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/compiler/spring13/notes/10.shtml) or [this one](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/farrell/comp4.html)).

> > I need grammar to deal with (1 + 3) * 3 = 12 problem and 1 + 3 * 3 = 12

Here you are implying that *Plus* should have a higher precedence than *Multiply* (so not the typical [BODMAS](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html) precedence rules), are you sure that is what you want?  If so I hope you'll be able to see how to rework the above in your grammar to give you the precedence you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, I appreciate your answer. I did something like this, but it doesnt work for every option:

```
number        : Int | Hex | Oct
              ;
operation     : ( ('(') ( number ) (op=(Add|Subtract|Multiply|Divide|Power|Max|Min)) ( number ) (')') )
              | number
              ;
muldiv        : ( ( operation ) (op=(Multiply|Divide)) ( operation ) )
              |operation
              ;
addsub        : ( ( muldiv ) (op=(Add|Subtract)) ( muldiv ) )
              | muldiv
              ;
expression    : ( (addsub) (op=(Add|Subtract|Multiply|Divide|Power|Max|Min) (addsub)) )
              | addsub
              | number
              ;
```